# What does it mean to say $\partial/\partial x, \partial/\partial y, \partial/\partial z$ are "basis" for $T_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

I know that $T_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$ is a vector space, but I'm not sure what the exact definition of it is. When we say $\partial/\partial x, \partial/\partial y, \partial/\partial z$ are "basis" for $T_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$, is it intrinsically following from the "definition" of $T_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$? Or do I need to somehow consult geometric interpretation? Is there any concrete definition of $T_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$? Is it linked to the geometric pictures? How do I show, from here, that $\partial/\partial \rho, \partial/\partial \phi, \partial/\partial \theta$, where $\rho,\phi,\theta$ are spherical coordinates also form a "basis" for $T_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$? I guess I can show it by literally calculating the relationship between them, but is there any better way to see it?

Comment: $T_p \mathbb{R}^n$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ with the vector $e_i$ from the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You need to get used with the notion of tangent space from manyfold theory to understand those definitions

Comment: " I'm not sure what the exact definition of it is" then how could you possibly expect to solve problems about it? When you're trying to prove something, knowing the definitions has to come _before_ anything else.

Comment: If you read my question, that's what I was asking

Comment: jk001 you need to tag @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich i posted answer. is it correct? the definition is kind of hard to understand at 1st. $T_p$ is  a bunch of arrows while $\mathcal D_p$ is indeed what OP is looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the basis of $T_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$ you're looking for is $\partial/\partial x|_p, \partial/\partial y|_p, \partial/\partial z|_p$. It's like this:

$T_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$ consists of tangent vectors to the point $p$ in $\mathbb R^3$. So literally it's a bunch of one-sided arrows that begin at $p$ and then point somewhere in $\mathbb R^3$.

Now, as $\mathbb R$-vector spaces, $T_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$ is $\mathbb R$-isomorphic to $\mathcal D_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$, where the latter consists of derivations at $p$, defined as maps $D: C_p^{\infty}(\mathbb R^3) \ \to \mathbb R$ that are $\mathbb R$-linear and satisfy the Leibniz rule $D(fg) = g(p) D(f)  + f(p) D(g)$, for all $f,g$ s.t. their germs are $[f],[g] \in C_p^{\infty}(\mathbb R^3)$.

What are these mysterious derivations at $p$? What do they look like? How do we describe them? What do we know about them? It's such an intimidating concept! And how do they relate to the arrows earlier?

Actually these derivations at $p$ are $\mathbb R$-linear combinations of :

$$\{\partial/\partial x|_p, \partial/\partial y|_p, \partial/\partial z|_p\}$$

So, the underlying set of  $\mathcal D_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$ is

$$\{a\partial/\partial x|_p+b\partial/\partial y|_p+c\partial/\partial z|_p\}_{a,b,c \in \mathbb R}$$

So for example we have some $p \in \mathbb R^3$ and then $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$, $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^3)$. Obtain the germ $[f] \in C_p^{\infty}(\mathbb R^3)$. Let's say $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$. Then for $D=\partial/\partial x|_p+2\partial/\partial y|_p+3\partial/\partial z|_p$, we can do like $D(f) = \partial/\partial x|_p(f)+2\partial/\partial y|_p(f)+3\partial/\partial z|_p(f)$. But anyway, this operator $D \in \mathcal D_p{\mathbb{R}^3}$ corresponds to the arrow pointing in the direction $(1,2,3)$ and beginning at the point $p$.

So yeah the isomorphism is between a bunch of arrows and a bunch of operators.